# why std::max_element over std::map within some lower_bound not working?

Tags: c++, stl, stdmap

I am not sure why the following snippet is not working:
The `lower_bound` call return the key 7, which is expected. Then the `std::max_element` between `begin()` and `lower_bound()` iterator should return 6, as it should search between key 4 and key 7 and the max value is 6 for key 7.
But it's returning the last `pair(15, 12)` for some reason which I can't figure out.

```
bool cmp(const std::pair<T, T>& p1, const std::pair<T, T>& p2) 
{
    return p1.second < p2.second;
}

int main()
{
    std::map< T, T, std::greater<T> > store;
    std::map< T, T, std::greater<T> >::iterator found_max, lower;

    store[ 4 ] = 2;
    store[ 7 ] = 6;
    store[ 10 ] = 2;
    store[ 15 ] = 12;
    lower = store.lower_bound( 8 );

    printf("%ld %ld\n", lower->first,lower->second);

    found_max = std::max_element(store.begin(), lower, cmp);
    printf("%ld %ld\n", found_max->first,found_max->second);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The default ordering for `map` (using `std::less<T>`) orders items from smallest to largest. Specifying `std::greater<T>` means they'll be ordered from largest to smallest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
std::map< T, T, std::greater<T> > store;
```

`store` has key sorted in *descending* order. Thus, `[store.begin(), lower)` contains `(15, 22)` and `(10, 2)`. The element with maximum value is `(15, 22)`.

Comment: That's correct, the following call should give me the corrent result.

`found_max = std::max_element(lower, store.end(), cmp)`